# Custom Matlab pushbutton appearance with Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, matlab, look-and-feel

I want to change the appearance of a Matlab pushbutton with Java. For it, I use the application [Findjobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317). However, because of I do not know Java, I have troubles to use Java classes properly that I need to get my button has rounded corners. Based on the information found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)), I have tried to set up the button with the class BorderFactory:

```
hButton = uicontrol('string','click me!');
jButton = findjobj(hButton);
jButton.setCursor(java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
jButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(red,1,true));
```

But this does not work. I got the following error message:

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'red'.

    Error in ==> de at 4
    jButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(red,1,true));
```

**EDIT:** I realize I forgot to include the Java classes for color and LineBorder. After fixing it, the code looks like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','click me!',...
    'Units','normalized','Position',[0.156 0.64 0.688 0.1],'FontSize',9,...
    'ForegroundColor','w','BackgroundColor','k');
jButton = findjobj(hButton);
jButton.setCursor(java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
jButton.setBorder(LineBorder(Color.white,5,true));
```

However, the result still be unpleased for me. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oblck.png) is the final appearance. I can get the corners to be rounded.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a _complete_ [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Perhaps now you find the question more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *rounded* buttons, you'll have to use a [Look & Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) whose button UI delegate draws rounded buttons. Examples include `com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706684/230513), and `javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel`, shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html). You can also implement your own `ButtonUI` and `Border`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513), but you'll have decide if it's worth the effort.

Addendum: Looking at this related Matlab [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9241039/230513) and the relevant Swing [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), note that "If you are going to set the L&F, you should do it as the very *first* step in your application."

Answer (score 2):

That should probably be `Color.red` or `Color.RED`.

---

Note that the `BorderFactory` method used there was only introduced in Java 1.7 (recently).  To make it compatible with versions back to 1.3, use the direct [`LineBorder(Color,int,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html#LineBorder%28java.awt.Color,%20int,%20boolean%29) constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried both but none of them works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have just edited my question but the results are not fine.